# JSONArray equivalent to JSONObject's .has() method?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I've been using this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(output);

if (json.has("errors"))
{
}
```

Now I have a JSONArray... how do I check for it having a child called "errors"?

Comment: Iterate thru the array?

Comment: An array doesn't have elements *named* anything... it just has elements. Try to give an example of the JSON you want to look through (e.g. one example where it would return true, and one where it would return false) and I suspect you'll find that you get stuck just trying to write that example...

Comment: Your same IF clause is able to check the array in he json..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONArray array;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
    JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);

    if (json.has("errors")){
        //magic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch block like this :

```
    boolean arrayexists = true;
    try{ 
      json.has("errors") }
    catch(Exception e){
     arrayexists = false;}
    if (arrayexists) {
    //majic
    }
```